# How to mock python elasticsearch client and test without starting an elasticserver?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, testing, mocking

I need to mock elasticsearch python client in order to test my APIs without actually starting the elastic server in my testing environment without actually changing my original code/API.

I came across elastic mock, which is a python elasticsearch client for mocking, but it lacks enough document to fit my case.
Link for python client:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/index.html

Link for elasticmock(python): https://pypi.org/project/ElasticMock/

There is the same elasticmock for javascript client, which replaces the connection component i.e. the HTTP layer in the Elasticsearch architecture.
Link for the Javascript client:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-testing.html#_elasticelasticsearch_mock

I have gone through a lot of stock overflow questions related to this, but everyone shows ways to mock the data. I don't want that.

I want to mock the HTTP connection part. I want to test the elasticsearch, without actually starting the elastic-server. So that my test environment would be independent of elasticsearch as an external dependency without changing my original code.

I have tried implementing the elastic mock for python, but due to lack of documentation, the demonstration didn't show ways to replace the elastic-server component and just hit static connection which would have been mocked.

All the related stack overflow questions relate to mocking data.